# Reactive approach Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm using reactive approach in angular2.

Where I have this form group.

```
     return this.fb.group({
             CreateDate:[''],
             UpdateDate:['']
      });
```

CreateDate and UpdateDate is not required to input. But when I clicked the submit button I get this error:

```
   core.umd.js:3010 Error: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'CreateDate'
```

Is there a way to fixed this issue when the form group value is empty.

Comment: Can you please post the HTML?

Comment: CreateDate and UpdateDate don't have a input fields. It was just a read only.

Comment: What do you need the formbuilder for then? I made a plunker for you. can you reproduce the problem there? http://plnkr.co/edit/nrHtxAhRG64cV7FNp0Q7

Comment: have you figured out the problem with this yet?

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in your code, you call:

```
this.myForm.setValue({
    UpdateDate: 'a value here'
    // but you forgot CreateDate
});
```

Hence the error.

If you use `setValue`, parameter must have the same structure as defined.
If you want to partially update your form values, use `patchValue`.

Double check your `setValue` and `patchValue` calls.